# In .Net Maui how do I create a ScrollVeiw within a ScrolView

Tags: scrollview, maui

Following the documentation I am able to create a ScrollView and also a following ScrollView by consuming these ScrollViews in a Grid.
However if I consume the Grid in a ScrollView I do not see the child ScrollViews, only the outer ScrollView.
I would like to have:
ScrollView
ScrollView
CollectionView - restricing the nuber of items displayed to 5
/ScrollView
ScrollView
CollectionView - restricing the nuber of items displayed to 5
/ScrollView
/ScrollView
I am testing on the Widows platform so I can compress and expand the form to test when a view scrolls.
I was able to do this in Xamarin Forms by settiing the height of the CollectionView but this does not work in .Net Maui.

Comment: please read [ask] before posting.  It helps a great deal if you actually post the relevant code rather than just describing it

Comment: *"I do not see the child ScrollViews"*. ScrollViews are tricky because their height is independent of the height of their content. This makes it hard for layout to know what space to give it. Each inner ScrollView needs either a) a `HeightRequest` or b) to be one row of a Grid, and the corresponding `Grid RowDefinition` determines the height.